# how to detect if window was refreshed or closed in js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

i know this question was asked before but i, can't get this to work.

I have a .aspx which contains a function on the onunload body tag.
This will refresh the parent page.

At this point, i need to know if the page was refreshed/reloaded, because this logic will trigger the func call everytime and close my "child" page.

This is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshparent(){
        window.opener.location.reload(true);
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

This is whay i want to do

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshparent(){
      if(page.wasclosed){
        window.opener.location.reload(true);
        window.close();
      }else{
   //do nothing
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```js
window.onload = function () {
      if (!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload();
      }
    }
```

once the page refreshed the #loaded is added to the url and once #loaded us detected it stops refreshing meaning "true". then you can use search params anywhere to see if the page was reloaded. You can add this in a setTimeout function or something else.

Comment: hi! thanks for the response, im not very good at js, can you explain me more about the "settimeout", why would i need it ?@david

Comment: i added the next code, it is not doing what it is supposed to: 
```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function refreshparent(){
        if (window.location.href.indexOf("loaded") > -1) {

        } else {
            window.opener.location.reload(true);
            window.close();
        }

    }


</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
      if (!window.location.hash) {
        window.location = window.location + '#loaded';
        window.location.reload();
      }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: it is adding the #loaded at the first load of the page